# IOS Get date from date string

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this date string 2014-05-01T00:00:00 and I would like to display it as 01/05/2014 00:00:00

I know that there are many questions and answers regarding this topic and I have looked hard but all questions I saw had the date format similar to desired format.  I tried the method below with or without the GMT zone setting

```
-(NSDate *) getDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
//    [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    return date;
}
```

Comment: It would help if your date format actually matched the format of the date in the string you are parsing.

Comment: To explain: Your string starts with "2014" which is probably a year. Your format string starts with "dd" which expects the number of a month. So how do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this date format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: That sorted it.  It gave me a temporary date 2014-05-01 00:00:00 +0000 which I ten formatted with [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"];

Comment: That's ok - please remember to accept the answer, though :)